# Problem 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations, tinker

I have a problem with php artisan tinker, can't find the reason why he wants a 'businesses' table but not a 'business' table.
Help me fix mistakes, I feel I did a lot of them)
My Problem :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'homestead.businesses' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `businesses`)'
```

my database business_table.php

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class BusinessTable extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Выполнение миграций.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('business', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('mail');
    $table->string('web-site');
    $table->timestamps();
    });
    }

    /**
    * Отмена миграций.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
    Schema::drop('business');
    }
}
```

My Controller: BusinessController.php

```php
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use \App\Models\Business;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class BusinessController extends Controller
    {
    public function index()
    {
    $business = \App\Models\Business::all();
    return view('business.index', compact('business'));
    }
    public  function store()
    {
    $business = new Business();
    $business->title = request()->input('title');
    $business->description = request()->input('description');
    $business->save();
    return redirect('/business');

    }
    }
```

My Model: Business.php

```php
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use \App\Models\Business;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class BusinessController extends Controller
    {
    public function index()
    {
    $business = \App\Models\Business::all();
    return view('business.index', compact('business'));
    }
    public  function store()
    {
    $business = new Business();
    $business->title = request()->input('title');
    $business->description = request()->input('description');
    $business->save();
    return redirect('/business');

    }
    }
```

My view file: business.blade.php

```php
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('title')Бізнес@endsection
@section ('main_content')
    <h1>Бизнес</h1>
    <p>
        <li>{{ $business->title}}</li>>
    </p>
@endsection
```

Image my error:
[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThVXi.png)

Comment: you've pasted the controller's code instead of the Model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by adding a table name in the model.

In the `Business.php` model:

By default Laravel tries to fetch the [plural name](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-plural) of a model. So `Business` will be `businesss`.

Internally Laravel checked:

`Str::plural('business') == "businesses"`

```php
class Business extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'business';
}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

### Best practice for creating a migration and model

`php artisan modelName -m` ----> make sure modelName is singular

In this way, Laravel automatically creates a plural version of a migration for you.

---

```php
 public function index()
 {
    $business = \App\Models\Business::all();
    return view('business', compact('business'));
 }
```

Here you are returning a collection of `business`. This means multiple rows of a table.
So you cannot use `$business->name` because `business` has multiple rows.

```php
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('title')Бізнес@endsection
@section ('main_content')
    <h1>Бизнес</h1>
    <p>
        @foreach ($business as $singleBusiness)
        <li>{{ $singleBusiness->title}}</li>>
        @endforeach
    </p>
@endsection
```

Comment: Thanks, could you still tell me how to correctly display the database in the file business.blade.php because I have an error there

Comment: @Mineral take a look i added those as well

Comment: you need to fix this `view('business', compact('business'));
`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what's wrong

Comment: it is your controller issue

Answer (score 1):

Laravel expect the database table name to be the plural version of the model.

In this case, your `business` model becomes a table of `businesses`.

Look here for more information.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#table-names

---

You have two options to solve this.

Specify the table name you want to use in your business model.

```
class Business extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'business';
}
```

Or change your migration to follow Laravel practices and create a businesses table.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class BusinessTable extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Выполнение миграций.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('mail');
    $table->string('web-site');
    $table->timestamps();
    });
    }

    /**
    * Отмена миграций.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
    Schema::drop('business');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the table inside your model

```
 protected $table = 'business';
```